# CSS Print Rotation and Scaling

Tags: css, printing

My CSS for golf scorecard is

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
  BODY {
    PAGE-BREAK-BEFORE: always;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) scale(.68,.68); 
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg) scale(.58,.58);
    zoom: 58%;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(Rotation=3);
}
</style>
```

IE scales but does not rotate. (Removing scaling does not change rotation issue.)

/* Removed non-IE part of question to more closely match only answer.  Will post separate question about FireFox */

Any advice?  Also played with idea of PHP lib DOMPDF but it breaks so easily on big tables and this is a golf scorecard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rotation you'll need some extra lines:

```
        -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
        transform:rotate(-90deg);
```

For scaling you'll have to add:

```
-moz-transform: scale(58);
```

Haven't tested this, but think it should work...

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  The rotation lines work thanks.  I already have the -moz-transform line in (see post) and issue is that if rotation is specified then scale fails to work.  Also - you mean .58, not 58.